# Azure Web Jobs - Accessing diferent ServiceBus queues with different configurations

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have two functions that are triggered when a message is received on two different queues.

I want that function A is called dequeuing one message per time, while function B with the default MaxConcurrentCalls.

Do I need to create two different WebJobs or do I have the opportunity to change ServiceBusConfiguration in the same WebJob in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can only be one ServiceBusConfiguration per WebJob. You're going to have to create two separate WebJobs if you want to vary the MaxConcurrentCalls. There's no way to change that in the ServiceBusTriggerAttribute either.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I concluded as well. Marco